# Wordpress Custom Post Type Archive doesn't load

Tags: php, wordpress

Wordpress Custom Post Type Archive template doesn't load, instead of archive-event.php, it loads archive.php. here is my code:

```
function university_post_types() {
  register_post_type('event', array(
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'events'),
    'has_archive' => true,
    'public' => true, 
    'labels' => array(
    'name' => 'Events',
    'add_new_item' => 'Add New Event',
    'edit_item' => 'Edit Event',
    'all_items' => 'All Events',
    'singular_name' => 'Event'
    ),
    'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-calendar'
  )); 
}
add_action('init', 'university_post_types');
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, flush your permalinks by saving them in the settings page.

Then check your plugins. In my test site I had Beaver Builder and it was bypassing my `archive-event.php`.

Edit: my original answer is not correct, the rewrite does not affect the template naming.

Comment: it didn't work. wordpress doesn't know archive-events.php

Comment: Have you flushed your permalink settings? That can sometimes mess about with your archive pages.